# discord.js message.member.roles.find is not a function

Tags: javascript

So i was trying to make a bot in discord.js, and i wanted to make a command that displays "test sucsessfull" if you have the right roles. But when i start the but it gives me this error: message.member.roles.find is not a function.

This is the code for the command:

```
if(command === "test"){
    if(message.member.roles.find("name", "wardens")){
    message.channel.send("test sucsessfull")
    }else{
    message.channel.send("you do not have the right permissions for this command!")
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like `member` has the `roles` property - https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member

Answer (score 0):

```
if(command === "test"){

  let roletest = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "wardens")

  if(message.member.roles.has(roletest.id)){
    message.channel.send("Test sucsessfull")
  } else {
    message.channel.send("you do not have the right permissions for this 
    command!")
  }

}
```